# expo-router pass params to a typescript class-defined page

Tags: typescript, react-native, routes, expo, expo-router

I pass some parameters to the screen using expo-routing but the screen is a class-defined component, how can I get params?
When I log props I have this: `{"segment": "home/index"}`

screen #1

```js
router.replace({ pathname: 'home', params: { id: '123' } });
```

screen #2

```js
export default class HomePage extends React.Component<HomePagePropsType, HomePageStateType> {

    constructor( props: HomePagePropsType ) {
        super( props );
        console.log( this.props )
    }
```

Comment: did you solve this? I'm struggling to do the same for an old project update with lot of classes

Comment: @AxxSilvera see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to use `useLocalSearchParams` from `expo-router`

Try this instead:

```
import { useLocalSearchParams } from 'expo-router'

const { id } = useLocalSearchParams();
```